# MySQL multiplying field result by the number of another field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm selecting a variety of columns from my database, and my query looks like this:

```sql
SELECT st.* , u.username creator, COUNT(DISTINCT se.sentenceid) AS sentences,
  COALESCE(SUM(v.vote), 0) score, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(se.text ORDER BY se.sentenceid SEPARATOR  ' ') text
FROM stories st
JOIN sentences se ON st.storyid = se.storyid
LEFT OUTER JOIN votes v ON st.storyid = v.storyid
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON st.creatorid = u.userid
GROUP BY st.storyid
LIMIT 30
```

This query works on everything except the score. The outputted score is the number of sentences multiplied by the actual score. My `votes` table looks like this:

```
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| userid  | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| storyid | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| vote    | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

`vote` contains a value of either 1 or -1.

---

How would I modify my query to receive the actual score?

Comment: Can you please create an sqlfiddle with some sample data?

Comment: @xception - Yeah, I'll start on that now...

Comment: @xception - Nevermind, the question got answered before I finished. I'll do that for my next SQL question, though.

Comment: Ok, please do that, it's much easier to understand when we know between which tables there are 1-1 connections and which are 1 to many or many to many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT st.* , u.username creator, COUNT(DISTINCT se.sentenceid) AS sentences,
  COALESCE((SELECT SUM(v.vote)
            FROM votes v
            WHERE st.storyid = v.storyid), 0) score, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(se.text ORDER BY se.sentenceid SEPARATOR  ' ') text
FROM stories st
JOIN sentences se ON st.storyid = se.storyid
LEFT OUTER JOIN users u ON st.creatorid = u.userid
GROUP BY st.storyid
LIMIT 30
```

Because each story can have many sentences and many votes, you're getting a cartesian product by multiplying out all the possible joins.